# What's the difference in use between »Was bedeutet das« and »Was hat es damit auf sich«?

Tags: difference

Is there a difference in use between the two expressions?

According to the dict.cc and the Pons Dictionary:

> [Was hat es damit auf sich? = What does it mean?](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Was%20hat%20es%20damit%20auf%20sich%3F)
>
> [Was bedeutet das? =  What does that mean?](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=Was%20bedeutet%20das&l=deen&in=&lf=de) *or* [What's the
>   meaning of this?](http://www.dict.cc/?s=was%20bedeutet%20das)

Originally, I came across the expression *damit auf sich hat* in the *FAZ.net* article “[Social Dining. Jetzt Mahl ehrlich](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/stil/essen-trinken/neues-social-dining-konzept-story-teller-14772424-p2.html)”. I'm quoting below the paragraph where the expression appeared:

> Beim dritten Gang steht es den Gästen frei, sich selbst einen Gesprächspartner auszusuchen. Ich setze mich zu Lynn. Die platinblonde Mitfünfzigerin blieb mir mit ihrem schnörkellosen Pixie-Cut und der auffälligen, schwarzgerahmten Brille aus der Vorstellungsrunde besonders im Gedächtnis. Nicht zuletzt, weil einer ihrer drei Begriffe „Burlesque“ war. Als ich sie frage, was es **damit auf sich hat**, entgegnet sie mir leicht aufbrausend, dass es sie langweile, dass sie jeder danach fragt: „Wo bleibt der Pep bei diesen Gesprächen?“ Genüsslich löffle ich meinen Schokokuchen mit Crème-fraîche-Eis und mexikanischer Vanille, während sich unserem Gespräch drei weitere Teilnehmerinnen anschließen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Was bedeutet das?" literally means *What does that mean?*

"Was hat es damit auf sich?" sounds more like *What's the deal with that?* or *What's that all about?*

In your example, if the author had asked **was das bedeutet** instead of **was es damit auf sich hat**, it would have suggested that he doesn't understand the meaning of the word Burlesque (although the interpretation that he just didn't understand it in that specific context would also have been available).

Answer (score 1):

*Was hat es damit auf sich* ist die allgemeinere Frage, während "was bedeutet das" auf eine Bedeutung verweist, etwas das gedeutet werden muss, also ein Zeichen ist.

So kann man fragen, was es bei einer Espressomaschine mit der Dampfdüse auf sich hat, weil diese eine Funktion hat; eine Frage nach ihrer Bedeutung wäre ein Missverständnis. Dagegen kann man zur Kontrollleuchte, die anzeigt, wann das Wasser heiß genug zum Brühen ist, mit beiden Formulierungen fragen, denn die Lampe will etwas bedeuten, ihr Leuchten bedarf der Interpretation.

Allerdings neigen Abergläubige Menschen dazu, in allen möglichen Vorkommnissen Bedeutungen zu lesen und Tiefenpsychologen könnten die Form der Aufschäumdüse zum Anlass für Deutungen nehmen. Es hängt also, wie so oft, am Kontext.

Der User sgf weist deshalb zurecht darauf hin, dass bei dem selten benutzten Wort *Burlesque* die Frage nach der Wortbedeutung naheliegt, zumal es um Begriffe geht, so dass es hier ratsam ist, die Frage so zu formulieren, dass man dieser Interpretation nicht noch entgegenkommt.